# android c2dm push just work in android 4.0 but lower

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I have a app. And has push notification function. But I find that just work on android 4.0 or 4.1, but doesn't work in 2.2 or 3.x. What is the reason?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

C2dm is deprecated right now and you can use GCM instead which support from API 8 up to 17

[And you can start from here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Comment: yes, but actually, my mean GCM, and it is running normally on andorid 4.0, but I don't know why does it not work on 2.2?